# Taking input from a JComboBox and putting it into a preparedstatement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, jcombobox

What I want to do is to print out information from a mysql table by using a jcombobox to select the information.

Here is the code for the jcombobox

```
private static String[] homeTeam = { "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Cardiff", "Chelsea"};                                            
private static JComboBox box1 = new JComboBox(homeTeam);
private static String[] awayTeam = { "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Cardiff", "Chelsea"};                                                             
private static JComboBox box2 = new JComboBox(awayTeam);
```

And this is the code for the preparedstatement

```
try 
    {
        //Sets up the connedtion to the database and installs drivers which are required.

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                                                                        

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "username", "password");        


        String BoxSelectedItem1 = box1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String BoxSelectedItem2 = box2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM PreviousSeasons WHERE HomeTeam=? and AwayTeam=?";
        PreparedStatement prepst;            

        prepst =  con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        prepst.setString(1,BoxSelectedItem1);
        prepst.setString(2,BoxSelectedItem2);
        rs = prepst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) 
        {

            hometeam = rs.getString("HomeTeam");
            awayteam = rs.getString("AwayTeam");                    
            result = rs.getString("Result");                    


            custs = (hometeam + "," + awayteam + "," + result);     
            SeasonResults add = SeasonResults.add(hometeam, awayteam, result);
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error " +e);                                                                               
    }
```

And this is the code for the jbutton where I try to print out the result

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{           
        if("Predict".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,result);
            //System.out.println(result);

}
}
```

"Predict" is the name of the jbutton. I have another jbutton which resets the jcombobox and that works so I know there isn't any problems with actionlisteners for the jbuttons.

When I press the button I don't get a response. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you set an action command for this button (using `setActionCommand("Predict")`)?. Otherwise did you try `if(e.getSource() == yourButton)`?

Comment: Yes, I have as this; predict.addActionListener(this);
        predict.setActionCommand("Predict");

Comment: Could you show the code for you GUI? (the relevant parts)

Comment: Do you mean the code for the jbutton?  private JButton predict = new JButton("Predict");

Comment: Did you set the action listener for the button? If yes, please post your code, because we can't say anything with what you provided, just suppositions.

Comment: Yeah, I used the code I posted 9 mins ago.